# x86-64 assembler language dialect for the listings package

Tags: listings

I'm writing a paper with a lot of x86-64 code listings in it. Unfortunately, the *listings* package itself does not have support for x86-64 instructions and register names (which are just named different than the 32 bit counterparts).

Does anyone have the code to configure the package to support that?

Comment: The package itself provides the possibility of define new languages. Thus you just have to follow the rules explained in the documentation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [documentation for listings](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) describes the `\lstdefinelanguage` macro, which can be used to define new languages as extensions of others.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage
   [x64]{Assembler}     % add a "x64" dialect of Assembler
   [x86masm]{Assembler} % based on the "x86masm" dialect
   % with these extra keywords:
   {morekeywords={CDQE,CQO,CMPSQ,CMPXCHG16B,JRCXZ,LODSQ,MOVSXD, %
                  POPFQ,PUSHFQ,SCASQ,STOSQ,IRETQ,RDTSCP,SWAPGS, %
                  rax,rdx,rcx,rbx,rsi,rdi,rsp,rbp, %
                  r8,r8d,r8w,r8b,r9,r9d,r9w,r9b, %
                  r10,r10d,r10w,r10b,r11,r11d,r11w,r11b, %
                  r12,r12d,r12w,r12b,r13,r13d,r13w,r13b, %
                  r14,r14d,r14w,r14b,r15,r15d,r15w,r15b}} % etc.

\lstset{language=[x64]Assembler}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
  cdqe 1, r8
  push 1
  add rsp, 4
  push 1
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Which looks a little like:

[image: output of the above LaTeX]

(I've just added the instructions listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#Added_with_x86-64) and only some of the registers, you can easily add any more that you use.)